# Manual line break in object summary for code insite etc

Tags: c#

when setting a summary for a property / field / method etc.. is it possible to manually break the lines without using the para (paragraph break)

```
/// <summary>
/// line one
/// line two
/// </summary>
public int member{get;set;}
```

On hover, this shows

```
int member
line one line two
```

Adding `<para>` ??? `</para>` tags like

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>line one</para>
/// <para>line two<para>
/// </summary>
public int member{get;set}
```

shows

```
int member
line one

line two
```

What I am looking for is

```
int member
line one
line two
```

Notice that there is not a blank line between line one and line two

Comment: If you don't want to add the <para>[empty character]</para>, you can always use a self closing <para /> to break the text. /// <summary>
        /// This is the first line.
        /// <para />
        /// New line.
        /// </summary>

Comment: Every instance of using the <para> (which is a paragraph break) creates an blank line between the two text lines. All I am looking for is the new line code, not the new paragraph code.

Comment: **nvoigt,** I can fully understand how you think that this question has been asked and answered, but in my opinion, the answers (which I have reviewed before asking) create a blank line between the two blocks of text, something I do not want.

Comment: Obviously you did not try the self closing tag or you would know that's not true. I just tested that before posting the comment for you.

Comment: **Jacob** here is the actual code that I tried your suggestion...`/// <summary>
    /// <seealso cref="short"/> 16-bit signed integer type
    /// <para />
    /// -32,768 ~ +32,767
    /// </summary>
    public class SMALLINT` and the same problem occurs.... on rollover it still creates a blank line between the 16-bit signed integer type line abd the -32,768 ~ +32,767 line.

Comment: I agree that the non-self closing tags do produce a double line break, however, the self closing tag in my environment is producing a single line break, or new line.

Comment: Then, I presume , there is an environment setting that affects this. If I could work it out, I would send you a screen shot of the actual rollover event